# Word or excel (2007) document left open

Tags: microsoft-office-2007

We run a network with a domain controller under Windows 2000 5.00 Service Pack 4.

Somebody left an Excel document open and everybody else cannot fill it.

How can I find which person (or computer) kept the document open?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the computer that has the file stored, you can check for open files in the "manage" option of right clicking my computer, shared folders, open files.

Comment: Start -> Run -> fsmgmt.msc

Answer (score 0):

I've always been a fan of [WhoLockMe](http://www.dr-hoiby.com/WhoLockMe/). It should show you user as well as program.